# Set margin-top to a % of the parent element's height

Tags: css

I want an element's margin-top to be a % of the parent elements height.

For example if I have div that has height 100px, I want to create a p element inside of it that has margin-top: 25px, except by setting the p element's margin with % so it can handle its parent changing height.

Edit: For those that think this is obvious - you can't use margin-top: 25%. %'s for the box model except height use the parent element's width. So you are setting it to 25% of the parent div's width if you use margin-top: 25%.

Comment: uhm... margin-top : 25%; ?

Comment: Nah @brett, It's not margin-top 25%. margin-top %'s use the element's width for sizing.

Comment: First impression. :p hrm.. now I am interested. :) is javascript an option, or are you expecting a purely css solution as tagged?

Comment: CSS would be ideal :) js would be pretty easy - but will stutter on resize if your browser is doing any other processing so will look cheap

Comment: why you don't use `translateY()` instead of margin-top?

Comment: oooo thats interesting, haven't tried it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I see as one of the solution:

```
 <div style="height:100px; background-color:red; color:white; position:relative;">
     <div style="top: 25%;position: absolute;">
         <p> I want an elements margin-top to be a % of t</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning the element instead of giving it a margin, like so:

```
p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}
```

[Demo for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/42ZfA/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to measure the parent element's height after it has been rendered (offsetHeight) and then divide it by 4 and assign the result to the childs top or marginTop property.

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var child = document.getElementById("child");
var marginVal = (parent.offsetHeight)/4;
child.style.top = marginVal+"px";
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nillervision/AwqJK/

If you wrap the js in a function you can call it when the page is loaded (window.onload) and when the browser get resized if that changes the parent elements size (window.onresize)

Comment: Thanke Nillervision, but not accepting JS answers at the moment